# Remove multiple users from PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql

I have about 50 users that needs to be removed. I can drop the users one after another by running drop command but I was wondering if I could get an answer that would significantly reduce the number of queries. Fairly new to psql, just wanted to know if there exists an efficient way or a function that would help me achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you tried `drop role role1, role2, role3, ...`?

Comment: Guess that's the only way. Is there any way I can fetch or read the role/users from a file (file that contains the list of users/roles)?

Comment: you can execute a query from a file using psql. if you have the roles in a file just prepend `drop table` before the comma-separated list and then you could use `psql -h host -u uname -d dbname -f /path/to/drop.sql`

Comment: Thanks @HaleemurAli it worked! Just had to add commas in the file.